# Can you give an animal a tranquilizer, and proceed to slaughter it?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Can you shoot an animal with a tranquilizer, or feed a tranquilizer to an animal, and proceed to slaughter it in a kosher manner?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47281/759

Comment: Short answer, **no**; long answer, also no.....don't have the sources offhand. See the linked question above, some articles of interest are linked to in the comments.

Comment: @Shokhet of all people, you should answer this :)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I know :) ....I know the answer, but don't have good sources for it.....I hope to find good sources soonish ;-) [if through this question, fine; if not, I'll answer!]

Comment: Doesn't a midrash say that Esau would shoot an animal to maim it and then slaughter it according to halachic necessity? I remember hearing this at least once and I feel like it applies here.

Comment: @Tim yeah, I noticed the word "kosherly" .....hadn't realized that it could be adverbed :P .....edit approved!

Comment: Even if it would be kosher, eating the meat would likely tranquilize the person eating it, so it becomes very impractical.

Comment: @rosenjcb I don't think we can learn halacha from Esau who lived before the Torah was given. The Avot did things forbidden today

Answer (score 4):

Generally the answer is no. This came up in the 1930s in Germany, where the laws were demanding that animals be stunned before slaughter. Rabbi Yechiel Yaakov Weinberg wrote on the subject at length and corresponded with many great authorities, but at the end of the day Rabbi Chaim Ozer Grozinski put his foot down that the practical answer was "no."

Rabbi Weinberg's work of responsa, *Sridei Aish*, has a lengthy addendum containing his correspondence on the subject.

One concern is the stunning/tranquilizing may injure the animal, and we require that the animal be in good shape just before slaughter. Another is that we want maximum bleed-out just after slaughter, which is accomplished when the animal has a fully-functioning nervous system.

Comment: I'm [looking for sources](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48235/can-you-shoot-or-feed-an-animal-with-a-tranquilizer-and-proceed-to-kosherly-sla/48238#comment127470_48235) on this topic. Do you have more specific *mareh mekomos*?

Comment: @Shokhet there's a kuntress printed at the back of newer editions of the Sridei Aish. (It's also on the Bar Ilan CD/website.)

Comment: @Shokhet be forewarned -- your notion of Daas Torah may be challenged. You'll see R' Chaim Ozer writing in the early 1930s that the German government will soon come to its senses and allow traditional shechita.

Comment: wasn't the main reason this was done to draw a line for goim not to push us publicly? "Rabbi Chaim Ozer Grozinski put his foot down that the practical answer was "no."? "

Answer (score 0):

what will stop you (what is the possible transgression?),

but if you want to eat it the possible problems are,

1. the chemicals that you put in the animal are not healthy (i heard it is recommended to wait a few days for them to leave the body), [i found on google](http://polarbearscience.com/2014/02/26/tranquilizing-polar-bears-and-meat-tainted-with-drugs/)
2. when you shoot it with a needle you need to be careful not to puncture the organs which become traif from a hole, i.e. esophagus, lungs, stomach, gallbladder, part of the spleen, intestines, uterus [(shach, yora daiya, 29.3)](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3543)

Comment: There are more problems than just these -- the animal cannot be tranquilized when shechted. I'll see if I can find better sources, but also see [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47281/759)

Comment: @Shokhet that the blood will not leave the body?

Comment: It's [inhumane](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/222246/jewish/Whats-Wrong-with-Stunning.htm), and may cause *treifos* even without hitting vital organs....I don't have very good sources offhand, I'll come back with an answer if/when I do.

Comment: @Shokhet One would hope to find a better website that Chabad.org that addresses whether or not stunning is inhumane (particularly vis a vis traditional shechita).

Comment: @mevaqesh See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67431/5120

Comment: But it is not regarding tranquilizer