# Are there proofs to Torah Shebeal Peh from Torah Shebechtav?

Tags: sources-mekorot, oral-torah, written-torah

Are there any proofs or hints to the oral Torah from the written Torah?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77977/759

Comment: See the Ba'al HaTurim for an extensive list of numerical hints to the Oral Torah from the Written Torah.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Torah Man and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4):

In [Hilchot Shechitah (1:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Ritual_Slaughter.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the Rambam writes:

זביחה זו האמורה בתורה סתם--צריך לפרש אותה, ולידע באיזה מקום מן הבהמה שוחטין, וכמה הוא שיעור השחיטה, ובאיזה דבר שוחטין, ומתי שוחטין, והיכן שוחטין, וכיצד שוחטין, ומה הן הדברים המפסידין את השחיטה, ומי הוא השוחט.  ועל כל הדרכים האלו, ציוונו בתורה ואמר "וזבחת מבקרך ומצאנך . . . **כאשר ציוויתיך**--ואכלת, בשעריך" (דברים יב,כא), שכל הדברים האלו **על פה ציווה בהן משה רבנו כשאר תורה שבעל פה, שהיא הנקראת "מצוה"** (שמות כד,יב) כמו שביארנו בתחילת חיבור זה

In the [introduction to the Mishneh Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the Rambam writes:

כל המצוות שניתנו לו למשה בסיניי--בפירושן ניתנו, שנאמר "ואתנה לך את לוחות האבן, והתורה והמצוה" (שמות כד,יב):  "תורה", זו תורה שבכתב; ו"מצוה", זה פירושה.  וציוונו לעשות התורה, על פי המצוה.  **ומצוה זו, היא הנקראת תורה שבעל פה**.

In other words, when the Torah tells us that ritual slaughter is performed "as I have commanded you," the Torah itself is referencing the oral law, which teaches us the details of ritual slaughter that are unspecified in the text itself.

Comment: While there is a Mishneh Torah that is part of תורה שבכתב, the Rambam's Mishneh Torah is not it.

Comment: @Alex you'll never guess what the Rambam is quoting

Comment: But what he's quoting is not self-evidently referring to Torah Sheba'al Peh -- if it was then merely quoting the verse would suffice for your answer. It is, in fact, the Torah Sheba'al Peh's *interpretation* of the Torah Shebichtav that claims that the Torah Shebichtav is referring to the Torah Sheba'al Peh. And indeed those who reject the legitimacy of the Torah Sheba'al Peh (e.g. Karaites) explain the verse differently.

Comment: @Alex so you're looking for a verse that those who reject Torah shebe'al peh will view as referring to Torah shebe'al peh?

Comment: If there was such a verse then they probably wouldn't reject Torah Sheba'al Peh. Thus, I would think that the correct answer to the question of "is there a proof from Torah Shebichtav?" would be no. Now the question here does mention hints as well as proofs, so your answer does suffice for that.